# Spring JPA Hibernate, how to update automatic @ManyToOne value object already referenced on DB?

Tags: spring, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, reference

I'm principant on Spring, I want to create my **ClientServeur** for my app android.

My Beans:

```kotlin
@Entity
data class Aliment(

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val numAliment: Long,

    val nomFrAliment: String,

    val nomAnAliment: String,

    val numGenre: Float,

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "num_genre")
    val genre : Genre
) {
    constructor() : this(0, "inconnu", "inconnu", 0f, Genre()) {
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Entity
data class Genre(

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        val numGenre: Float,

        val nomAnGenre: String,
        val nomFrGenre: String

) {
    constructor() : this(0.0f, "", "")
}
```

My DB tables MYSQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `aliment` (
  `num_aliment` integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nom_fr_aliment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `nom_an_aliment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `num_genre` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`num_aliment`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`num_genre`) REFERENCES `genre`(`num_genre`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `genre` (
  `num_genre` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `nom_an_genre` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `nom_fr_genre` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`num_genre`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

What I want to do, it's **when I request some Aliment**, the value **genre : Genre** will be automaticaly **update** by them **foreign key** reference.

**How can I do that ?**

**More details**

On my **request on my mobile app** : I call my http request, and the client return me the JsonObject but the genre value is null ( I want my client search the num_genre correspondent and put it on my value genre).
So for the moment I do an other request to take the genre correspondent and update this value genre = null to the genre correspondent.

On the **client** I have:

**Repository**

```kotlin
@Repository
interface AlimRepository : JpaRepository<Aliment, Long> {

    fun findAlimentsByNomFrAlimentStartingWith(nomFrAliment: String): List<Aliment>
    fun findAlimentsByNomFrAlimentContains(nomFrAliment: String): List<Aliment>
    fun findAlimentsByNomAnAlimentStartsWith(nomAnAliment: String): List<Aliment>
    fun findAlimentsByNumGenre(numAliment: Float): List<Aliment>

}
```

```kotlin
@Repository
interface GenreRepository : JpaRepository<Genre, Float>
```

And I have my **Controllers**:

```kotlin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/alim")
class AlimController(private val alimRepository: AlimRepository) {

    /**
     * RETURN full list Aliments
     *
     * @link : http://localhost:8080/alim/all
     */
    @GetMapping("/all")

    fun getAllAliments(): List<Aliment> {
        println("/alim/all")
        return alimRepository.findAll()
    }

    /**
     * RETURN alim by num aliment ( works like Id )
     *
     * @link : http://localhost:8080/alim/num/2000
     */
    @GetMapping("/num/{numAliment}")
    fun getAlimByNum(@PathVariable(value = "numAliment") alimId: Long): ResponseEntity<Aliment> {
        println("/alim/num/$alimId")
        return alimRepository.findById(alimId).map { aliment ->
            ResponseEntity.ok(aliment)
        }.orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build())
    }

    /**
     * RETURN ListAlims by StartingWith nameFr
     *
     * @link : http://localhost:8080/alim/name_fr/pat
     */
    @GetMapping("/name_fr_start/{nomFrAliment}")
    fun getAlimsByNameFrStartingWith(@PathVariable("nomFrAliment") nomFrAliment: String): List<Aliment> {
        println("/alim/name_fr_start/$nomFrAliment")
        return alimRepository.findAlimentsByNomFrAlimentStartingWith(nomFrAliment)
    }
    /**
     * RETURN ListAlims by contain nameFr
     *
     * @link : http://localhost:8080/alim/name_fr/pat
     */
    @GetMapping("/name_fr_contain/{nomFrAliment}")
    fun getAlimsByNameFrContains(@PathVariable("nomFrAliment") nomFrAliment: String): List<Aliment> {
        println("/alim/name_fr_contain/$nomFrAliment")
        return alimRepository.findAlimentsByNomFrAlimentContains(nomFrAliment)
    }

    /**
     * RETURN ListAlims by containing nameEn
     *
     * @link : http://localhost:8080/alim/name_en/pota
     */
    @GetMapping("/name_en/{nomAnAliment}")
    fun getAlimsByNameEn(@PathVariable("nomAnAliment") nomAnAliment: String): List<Aliment> {
        println("/alim/name_en/$nomAnAliment")
        return alimRepository.findAlimentsByNomAnAlimentStartsWith(nomAnAliment)
    }

    /**
     * RETURN listAlims find by numGenre
     *
     * @link : http://localhost:8080/alim/num_genre/20
     */
    @GetMapping("/num_genre/{numGenre}")
    fun getAlimByNumGenre(@PathVariable("numGenre") numGenre: Float): List<Aliment> {
        println("/alim/num_genre/$numGenre")
        return alimRepository.findAlimentsByNumGenre(numGenre)
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/genre")
class GenreController(private val genreRepository: GenreRepository) {


    /**
     * RETURN full list Genre
     *
     * @link : http://localhost:8080/genre/all
     */
    @GetMapping("/all")
    fun getAllGenre(): List<Genre> {
        println("/genre/all")
        return genreRepository.findAll()
    }

    /**
     * RETURN genre by numGenre ( works like Id )
     *
     * @link : http://localhost:8080/genre/num_genre/23.5
     */
    @GetMapping("/num_genre/{numGenre}")
    fun getGenreByNumGenre(@PathVariable(value = "numGenre") numId: Float): ResponseEntity<Genre> {
        println("/genre/num_genre/$numId")
        return genreRepository.findById(numId).map { genre ->
            ResponseEntity.ok(genre)
        }.orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build())
    }
}
```

Of course when I try this code I get this error:

```
2020-12-03 15:17:06.143 ERROR 14044 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Table [aliment] contains physical column name [num_genre] referred to by multiple logical column names: [num_genre], [numGenre]
```

Comment: What do you do in order to expect genre to be updated? Show the call-site please (where you create an Aliment / load it or whatever).

Comment: Hi, I make a response on an answer to put details

Comment: Hey! Please don't post refinements of the question as an answer. Pls edit your question and add (only relevant) details there. The code should be minimal but still showing your problem.

Comment: Hey, i update it.

Answer (score 0):

Since one `Aliment` can have many (`@ManyToOne`) `Genres` associated with it. The information which `Genre` belongs to which `Aliment` needs to be stored in the table of `Genre`, which is `genre`.

`genre` already has a field `num_genre` which is its primary key, with `@JoinColumn(name = "num_genre")` you instruct Hibernate to store the info which `Genre` belongs to which `Aliment` in that same column, which is not possible.

Long story short, if you remove `@JoinColumn(name = "num_genre")` it should work already, because Hibernate will create a column `alignment_id` in the `genre` table for you.

---

I would also remove `numGenre`, since it is not annotated in any way it won't be managed by Hibernate anyway and the associated `Genre` will already be represented by the `genre` property. The existence of this property should not cause an error though.

Comment: The client run but he say : Error executing DDL "alter table aliment add constraint FKdg2xocbcyc7qdlumg6lejxm6f foreign key (genre_num_genre) references genre (num_genre)" via JDBC Statement

Comment: My value genre on my Aliment still null

Comment: @MakiX pls, remove `numGenre` property from `Aliment`. Drop the database (easiest way if there is nothing to migrate) and restart the spring app.

Comment: Hibernate will built the schema from scratch then

Comment: @MakiX Does that solve your problem or is it not working? :)